# How to print current GMT time in a specific format in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, gmt

The format I have been given `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. However, this isn't working with my code which is

```
datetime.utcnow().strftime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

The output is simply:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'

Why does this not work? What is the fix ?

Comment: made the change

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) for the details of how to specify formats with `strftime` .

Comment: No I got my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Python uses the above linked directives to format time.

So, for example, if you try something like:

```
import datetime  

datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z")
```

This should display the format you mentioned in the right way

Comment: datetime.utcnow() :)

Comment: @gzerone you are an angel.